# How bootstrap works in general and particularly in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I’m reading Zend Framework manual and cannot understand how bootstrapping works particularly in ZF and in general.
They write:

> Your Bootstrap class defines what resources and components to
>   initialize.

Ok. It means that the Bootstrap class should be instantiated the first of all.
But then then they write about the configuration `ini` file. And there are directives about the `Bootstrap` class itself in it:

```
1.  bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
2.  bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
```

So as I understand it means that it is not the `Bootstarp` class that is instantiated the first of all. The first of all something has to read the configuration file, get the info about the `Bootstrap` class and having that info to instantiate. Otherwise there is no need to have info about the `Bootstrap` class in configuration file. Because I can just do this:

```
require_once(/application/bootstrap.php) 
$b = new Bootstrap();
```

and Bootstrap is instantiated.

But they say nothing about the one that reads the config file and then makes an instance of the `Bootstrap`.

1. How the Bootstrap really works?
2. Who instantiates it and on which stage?
3. They say that the `APPLICATION_PATH` is a constant. A constant has to be defined somewhere before it can be used. Where may it be defined if it is used in Bootstrap class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the `index.php` file that ships with ZF, this should answer most of those questions.

The `APPLICATION_PATH` constant is defined in `index.php`, and that is also where the `Zend_Application` object is created which simply bootstraps the application, and then runs it.

There are 2 ways to tell your `Zend_Application` where your bootstrap is located in ZF1.

First way (explicitly set):

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    array(
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'Bootstrap',
            'path' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/Bootstrap.php',
        ),
        'config' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
    )
);
```

In the above example, the bootstrap class and the bootstrap script are passed as part of the `$options` directly to `Zend_Application`'s constructor, along with the `application.ini` file.

If you put the bootstrap class and script in your `application.ini` file, then you can initialize `Zend_Application` like so:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    array('config' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini')
);
```

`Zend_Application` will process the `application.ini` file and gather the Bootstrap information from there.

You can then call `$application->bootstrap()->run();` to run the application.

To directly answer your questions:

1. The bootstrap sets up your application.  After processing your `ini` file, it is the first thing take takes place.  This sets up all the required components for your ZF application (e.g. Front Controller, Zend_View, Layouts, DB connection etc).
2. index.php instantiates it pretty much at the very beginning.
3. `APPLICATION_PATH` is defined immediately in index.php

Answer (score 2):

Here is my short explanation:

Bootstrap initializes framework resources, initializes framework configuration, loads classes and other framework preparation work, it is started in every request, started by index.php file in default configuration.

1. First `index.php` is called where `APPLICATION_PATH` constant is defined and is passed to `Application` class constructor.
2. Application class instance created in constructor framework reads configuration file and stores for later use.
3. Then framework bootstrapping begins:

   I.  Application/Bootstrap class instance created (Framework starts creating required plugins, resources which was defined in your *.ini file.)

   II. Takes your Custom bootstrap class and initializes methods with `init` prefix.

   III. Loads FrontController resource, and front  controller starts request dispatching process (Loads module, controller, views, calls plugin callbacks).

Overall you can track everything by yourself start from `index.php` file, then to library and try understand what classes are loaded, in what order.